# BackInTime Can't Remove Snapshot?

Tags: backup, backintime

I had my external drive power down during a snapshot due to a power failure and now the new_snapshot folder can't be removed.

At first, I thought that I could just give the program `sudo` permission, but this doesn't appear to work.

This is what happens upon using the GUI and trying to take a new snapshot:
[image: Snapshot]
[image: Can't remove snapshot]

Here is what it looks like from terminal:

```
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ backintime backup

Back In Time
Version: 1.1.12

Back In Time comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `backintime --license' for details.

INFO: Lock
INFO: Inhibit Suspend started. Reason: take snapshot
INFO: Mountpoint /home/sarah/.local/share/backintime/mnt/DB511438/mountpoint is already mounted
INFO: Take a new snapshot. Profile: 1 Main profile
INFO: Remove leftover 'new_snapshot' folder from last run
rm: cannot remove '/home/sarah/.local/share/backintime/mnt/1_14102/backintime/ConvergentRefuge/sarah/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/sarah/Desktop/Desktop/Utilities/Config/config': Directory not empty
WARNING: Command "rm -rf "/home/sarah/.local/share/backintime/mnt/1_14102/backintime/ConvergentRefuge/sarah/1/new_snapshot/backup"" returns 256
INFO: [qt4systrayicon] begin loop
rm: cannot remove '/home/sarah/.local/share/backintime/mnt/1_14102/backintime/ConvergentRefuge/sarah/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/sarah/Desktop/Desktop/Utilities/Config/config': Directory not empty
WARNING: Command "rm -rf "/home/sarah/.local/share/backintime/mnt/1_14102/backintime/ConvergentRefuge/sarah/1/new_snapshot"" returns 256
ERROR: Can't remove folder: /home/sarah/.local/share/backintime/mnt/1_14102/backintime/ConvergentRefuge/sarah/1/new_snapshot
notify-send  "Back In Time (sarah) : Main profile" "Can't remove folder: /home/sarah/.local/share/backintime/mnt/1_14102/backintime/ConvergentRefuge/sarah/1/new_snapshot"
ERROR: Failed to take snapshot !!!
notify-send  "Back In Time (sarah) : Main profile" "Failed to take snapshot 01/02/19 16:33:14 !!!"
INFO: Mountpoint /home/sarah/.local/share/backintime/mnt/DB511438/mountpoint still in use. Keep mounted
INFO: Unlock
INFO: Release inhibit Suspend
```

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04.01, and my backup is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The reason is, that Backintime sets all files on read-only after savint ghem. As a result a regular user cannot delete the snapshot directory anymore. You can solve this manually by deleting the directory "new snapshot" as root. If it is on a NAS you should log into the NAS and delete als root. But be careful. ;-)

BTW: At my system the same happens if backintime tries to delete old snapshots. It does not work because auf missing permissions. I would have expected that BIT can handle that, but at least on a QNAP NAS it does not work. Does anyone have an idea what can be done?